# Any ways to open Office(.doc,.ppt,.xls etc.) and PDF files in Windows Phone 8.1 application?

Tags: pdf, powerpoint, xls, windows-phone-8.1, doc

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 Viewer application.I need to open Office files such as `.ppt,.xls,.doc` etc and `pdf` files.I got `pdf` support from `ComponentOne`,but for Office types I did't get any supported library.There are [GDocs](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/gdocs/d3493945-5727-e011-854c-00237de2db9e),
[Isilo](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/isilo/8d994129-7cd5-df11-a844-00237de2db9e),[i-Clickr](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/i-clickr-lite/4ca51fc7-6511-e011-9264-00237de2db9e),[Presenter's View Pro](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/presenter-view-pro/26926b1b-a7c3-4b39-ac20-61231536f8d3) available in Store.How did they build such apps?

Also,I found that Good's [Discussion](http://community.good.com/thread/3882)

Leadtools Imaging [SDK](http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/windows-phone/default.htm) that I found is also related to this but converts docs to image then displays it.

I need a solution such that I can directly open .doc,.ppt,.xls,.pdf etc files using any paid/free library/Control available.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion's windows phone controls contain libraries for dealing with word and excel files.

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-phone/controls

http://www.syncfusion.com/sales/offers/winphone-hobbyist